# Chocolatey doesn't install

Tags: powershell, installation, chocolatey

Following the steps to install Chocolatey via Powershell doesn't work on my Windows 7 64bit PC. I'm following https://chocolatey.org/install#install-from-powershell-v3

- I have confirmed the ExecutionPolicy and that system path has
  Powershell;

  ```
  PS C:\Users\a> Get-ExecutionPolicy
  AllSigned

  PS C:\Users\a> ($env:Path).split(';')
  %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
  C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
  C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
  C:\Windows\system32
  C:\Windows
  C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
  C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
  C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
  C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
  C:\Program Files\smartmontools\bin
  ```
- Here are my error messages;

  ```
  PS C:\Users\a> iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
  ???# : The term '???#' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  At line:1 char:1
  + ???# =====================================================================
  + ~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (???#:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
  Getting Chocolatey from https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.10.5.
  !Test-Path : The term '!Test-Path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  At line:188 char:11
  + } elseif (!Test-Path $7zaExe) {
  +           ~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (!Test-Path:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  Extracting C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall...
  Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"
  At line:211 char:3
  +   $process.Start() | Out-Null
  +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

  Exception calling "BeginOutputReadLine" with "0" argument(s): "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."
  At line:212 char:3
  +   $process.BeginOutputReadLine()
  +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

  Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
  At line:213 char:3
  +   $process.WaitForExit()
  +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

  Unable to unzip package using 7zip. Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true' and call install again. Error: 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (code )
  At line:225 char:15
  +     default { throw "$errorMessage 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (code $exitC ...
  +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to unzip...n error (code ):String) [], RuntimeException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to unzip package using 7zip. Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true' and call install again. Error: 7-Zip signalled an unknown error (code )
  ```
- I have tried the error messages suggestion on the last line

  ```
  Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'
  ```

  But that only results in a whole series of other errors

Comment: AllSigned is currently not going to work due to some discovered bugs in PowerShell that we passed along to the PowerShell team. It will work again when 0.10.6 comes out. As for the other issue, that was introduced today with a BOM to deal with ensuring authenticode doesn't fail on unicode characters in non-BOM files (the second issue we discovered recently) - please file a proper issue so we can get it fixed.

Comment: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco (although we already have issues for allsigned and have fixed it) and https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey.org for the BOM install.ps1 script. Thanks!

Comment: I filed the issue at https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey.org/issues/512

Comment: This should now be working again.

Comment: Thank you @ferventcoder. Your support is unbelieveable.  I will wait for 0.10.6 as I now get a series of errors starting with "chocolateyInstaller.psm1 cannot be loaded ... hash of the file does not match the hash stored in the digital signature"

Comment: You can use Bypass for now to get it installed.

Comment: If you're ever in Perth, Western Australia, I owe you at least one beer!

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\admin\scripts> iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : ï»¿# =====================================================================
...
```

You're downloading a UTF-8-encoded file (the content begins with the characteristic UTF-8 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `ï»¿`), but it's being treated as ASCII text.

Besides:

> *I'm following https://chocolatey.org/install#install-from-powershell-v3.*

No, you're not. The website you referenced tells you to use

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

which works as advertised, whereas you're trying to use

```
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
```

If you want to use that approach you need to remove the BOM from the content before piping it into `Invoke-Expression`:

```
(iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing).Content -replace '^ï»¿' | iex
```

Comment: If you click on more options, you will see what he is linking - you would expect PowerShell to handle the file appropriately to see it is UTF8 b/c BOM (but clearly, this is not the case).

Comment: I tend to not go through "more options" when there's a working one right on the front page.